# Amazon ship date you provided was not beеween the order date and now

Tags: amazon-mws

We are using the Submit Feed and type is *POST_FLAT_FILE_FULFILLMENT_DATA* to process the Amazon order. We create a flat file that contains all info including ship date. But when we hit Submit Feed API for orders then it gives warning message that is:

> The ship-date or FulfillmentDate you provided (2023-02-14T07:00:00.000Z) was not between the order date (2023-02-12T00:00:00.000Z) and now (2023-02-14T06:23:27.042Z).

So, if script executed between 0:00 and 08:00, we got this error, in another time, this error does not occur.

Seems Amazon automatically makes +8  hours, but i can't find it on Amazon support.

Comment: Amazon has been inconsistent about whether its API timestamps are in local time, UTC, or Pacific time. Since Pacific time is 8 hours out from UTC, I'd suspect that's the source of your 8 hours.

Comment: 2023-02-14T06:23:27.042Z corresponds to the script execution time on the Linux server. The time there is in UTC. Perhaps, Amazon getting timestamp of server. But really, I wouldn't want to change the server to PST.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't add an offset of 8 hours to the timestamp before sending it to Amazon, then?

Comment: I don't see us sending the timestamp to amazon. Date only in the form YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Of note -usually  a timestamp  of 24 hours does not know its a new day when then 24 hour 1 second mark happens, it rolls back around to 00:00.  To handle a date changing you need to change the date yourself when you detect it goes over with your code.